# How to draw a circle using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a disc using Ti*k*Z whose two halves are of different color.

[image: like this]

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Only a disc with one color.

Comment: Then post the one-coloured disc as your Minimum Working Example. It shows why exactly you are stuck and provides people with a document to start from. It is easier and faster to help you that way and the help you get is likely to be more effective i.e. to solve the problem in a way which genuinely helps and is explicable etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities to realize this. I implemented a center coordinate, which is a bit more flexible. Explanations as comments:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Circle's center
    \coordinate (center) at (2,2);

    % Create a blue filled arc, starting 2 above the center, 
    % with a start angle of 90°, an end angle of 270° and a radius of 2
    \fill[blue] (center) + (0, 2) arc (90:270:2);

    % Create a red filled arc, starting 2 below the center, 
    % with a start angle of 270°, an end angle of 450° and a radius of 2
    \fill[red] (center) + (0, -2) arc (270:450:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Circle]

Answer (score 8):

All questions (very nearly almost) should include a Minimum Working Example i.e. code for a small document setting up the problem.

If you need to get started with TikZ, try the tutorials in the first part of the TikZ manual.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [red] (0,0) coordinate (a) arc (90:270:1) -- cycle;
  \fill [blue] (a) arc (90:-90:1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: half and half]

Answer (score 6):

How about a `path picture`?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{split fill/.style args={#1 and #2}{path picture={
    \fill [#1] (path picture bounding box.south west)
      rectangle (path picture bounding box.north);
    \fill [#2] (path picture bounding box.south)
      rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east);
}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz\foreach \i in {0,10,...,100}
  \path[split fill=red!\i!yellow and blue!\i!green] 
    (\i*3.6: 4) circle [radius=1]; 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{
  dimen = m,
  fillstyle = solid
}

% parameter
\def\radius{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-\radius,-\radius)(\radius,\radius)
  \pswedge[fillcolor = blue!60]{\radius}{90}{270}
  \pswedge[fillcolor = red]{\radius}{270}{90}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is change the value of `\radius` and the drawing will be adjusted accordingly.